# How to decode json data in sql for search?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gridview, yii, yii2

need some advice to solve problem with yii grid/POstgreSql search.

In table I have some row let's call - some_important_data.
For showing in gridview i write some code in MyModel.php afterFind() method.

```
    $someData           = $this->some_data ? json_decode(urldecode($this->some_data)) :'';
    if(!empty($someData)) {
        $this->searcheeReason   =  $someData->csr_refuse_reason;
        $this->witnessReason    =  $someData->csr_witness_reason;
    }
    ........
    if(!empty($this->starttime) && !empty($this->endtime) && !empty($csrPauseData->csr_colleague_reason)){
            $this->status       = "Rejected";
    }
```

Now I want to write Search Part in search method in MyMethodSearch.php and Order in my controller =>

```
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        $dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes'   => [
                'searchNum'         => [
                    'asc'  => ['responses.number' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['csresponses.number' => SORT_DESC]
                ],
                'searcheeReason' => ???
```

I try a lot of things, but I don't find any optimal way. One of that ways

=>

```
       SELECT substring(csresponses.some_data
               from (POSITION('%22csr_refuse_reason%22%3A%22' in 
                     csresponses.some_data) + 
                    LENGTH('%22csr_refuse_reason%22%3A%22')) 
                  for (POSITION('%22%2C%22' in 

              substring(csresponses.some_data
                    from (POSITION('%22csr_refuse_reason%22%3A%22' in 
                          csresponses.some_data) ) 
                    for (LENGTH( csresponses.some_data) -  
                        POSITION('%22csr_refuse_reason%22%3A%22' in csresponses.some_data)))) 
                        - LENGTH('%22use_firstname%22%3A%22')))

        from csresponses
```

Code written ofcourse with yii rules, it's just sql interpretation

Comment: You should really improve your DB structure - searching and sorting in URL-encoded JSON will be slow and unreliable. Maintaining this will be like hell.

Comment: yeh, I know , but I cann't change the db, I just need to dolve the problem with the better way and sen it...after that I can ask for changing db.